# "Код копирую в свой проект, и там он не работает" - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Вопрос: правильно ли подобран пример для [правила](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5664/213987).

Нужна ли запятая перед "и"?

> Код копирую в свой проект, и там он не работает.

Насколько я понимаю, здесь именно два простых предложения. С учётом того, что можно заменить "он" на "код", запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не обращайте внимания, что на что можно заменить, например масло на маргарин или сахар на сахарин.

Запятая нужна, потому что в процитированном ССП есть две основы: "копирую" (подразумевается опущенное "я" - подлежащее) и "он не работает".

Даже если бы "код" был подлежащим в первом предложении, "он" во втором - это другая часть речи, местоимение.